# Jquery Load Function with Error Message if taking too much time

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

Is there any way to handle the loading time, I mean when jquery load function taking too much time I want to show a error message. Following code is working perfectly.

```
var href=$(this).attr('href');
$('#load').load(href);
```

Please Help me ! Thanks .

Comment: `load()` is just a shortcut for `$.get` which is a shortcut for `$.ajax` which has a `timeOut` setting and a way to catch errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, and read [**Jquery ajax documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

---

```
var href=$(this).attr('href');
$.ajax({
    url: href,
    error: function(){
        // will fire when timeout is reached
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something
    },
    timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
});
```

Comment: No, above code is not working. It shows error while contents are loading.

Comment: you declired the the href fariable?

Comment: I mean, I use alert('Sample error');in error: function(){ //here }

Comment: If you tell me whats the problem im my code i can help you. because this is a right solution for your problem Tomb :)

Comment: Yes I declared it, in this way var href=$(this).attr('href');

Comment: If the request takes to muchtime you can cacel it and show error? with #Chakravarthy code? you cannot...

Comment: No, I can't because its alert when loading is done :(

Comment: with ajax function you can prevent request and catch errors. read documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/